# PHP POST to localhost from server

Tags: php, post, curl, localhost

I am using the RocketShip.it print server to print UPS labels, and am using cURL to send the label information to the print server.

The print server runs on localhost port 8080, so the URL that the data is being sent to is `http://localhost:8080`.

When the cURL post is initialized from localhost (ie. when testing the site on my local machine) the label prints correctly.

However, when the cURL is initialized from the server, cURL throws an error "couldn't connect to host".

Is there a way to send data from the server to localhost with cURL?

Comment: What URL do you use when you connect from server? Because for that server the url wont be localhost

Comment: http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Nope localhost can only be used from same computer. From another computer use this format:  `http://IpAddressOfThePrintServer:8080`

Comment: Hmm. I was hoping that since the cURL is started by the user clicking the print button, there would be a way to send the information back to the client.